# How to create a simple JSON in Groovy using JsonBuilder?

Tags: json, groovy

```
tool_name = 'test
product_name = 'test'
platform_name = 'test'

def my_json = new JsonBuilder()
def root = my_json name: tool_name, product: product_name, platform: platform_name
print my_json
```

What am I doing wrong?  I am trying to create a very basic (flat) json object to later send in a POST request.

something like:

```
{'name': 'test', 'product': 'test', 'platform': 'test'}
```

What is the easiest way to do this?  Can I use JsonBuilder or Slurper for this?  I am completely new to groovy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a `Map` and render it as JSON using `groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson()` helper method, e.g.

```
def tool_name = 'test'
def product_name = 'test'
def platform_name = 'test'

def map = [name: tool_name , product: product_name , platform: platform_name]

def json = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(map)

println​ json​
```

This example produces following output:

```
{'name': 'test', 'product': 'test', 'platform': 'test'}
```

If you want to use `groovy.json.JsonBuilder` then below example produces your expected output:

```
def tool_name = 'test' 
def product_name = 'test' 
def platform_name = 'test'

def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()        
builder {
    name tool_name
    product product_name
    platform platform_name
}
println builder.toString()​
```

`groovy.json.JsonSlurper` class is dedicated to reading JSON documents and manipulating them if needed.